# Cholesky factorization for positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I know that a matrix $A$ is positive definite and symmetric if and only if there exists a lower triangular matrix $L$ with nonzero diagonal such that $A = LL^T$.

I'm wondering if it similarly holds that a matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite and symmetric if and only if there exists a lower triangular matrix L (where zeros are permitted on the diagonal) such that $A=LL^T$.

The if part is easy since $x^TAx = x^TLL^Tx=||L^Tx||^2 \geq0$. The equality holds when $L^Tx=0$ which can only occur if there are zeros on the diagonals of $L$. Is the converse true? I ask because I want to know if I can use cholesky factorization to check if a hessian is PSD.

Comment: "matrices", not "matrixses".

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, but if $A$ is PSD then the choice of $L$ is not unique.  There is, however, a unique choice of $L$ whose size is $n \times r$ where $A$ is $n \times n$ with rank $r$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, could you kindly expand on the unique choice of $L$ $n\times r$ when $A$ is of rank $r$?

Comment: @epsilone See LDL decomposition on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)

Comment: @epsilone actually, the more direct explanation is that it follows from the uniqueness of $QR$ decomposition.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But AFAIK the uniqueness of the QR decomposition of a matrix $n\times n$ $A$ is guaranteed only if $A$ is of full rank. Would not be that a problem?

Comment: I ask a question on this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551985/uniqueness-of-a-reduced-rank-qr-decomposition

Comment: So what is us the answer for the question? Did you figure out with it?